# Does the byte size of an argument affect the overhead of an opaque function call?

Tags: c, performance, struct, function-calls

This is best asked with a code example:

```
typedef struct {
    ... // Fields take up many bytes (>= 32 bytes)
} some_struct;

void alternative_1(some_struct arg);
void alternative_2(const some_struct *arg);
```

Assuming that both function alternatives are implemented inside an already compiled binary (and therefore cannot be inlined), is there a difference in the function call overhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously yes:

When calling **alternative_1**, the whole struct data is pushed onto the stack prior to branching to the function (which may be quite a lot).

Whereas **alternative_2** only has a single pointer to the struct pushed onto the stack.

There is also a big difference when operating on the struct:

- In the case of **alternative_1** you work on a local copy.
- When modifying the struct in **alternative_2** you change the original data.

Its quite similar to a function receiving either an *integer* or a *pointer to an integer*.